# Почему сайт глючит, подтормаживает на клиенте? Особенно js.

Tags: jquery, производительность, javascript

Мучает уже очень долго 1 вопрос, решение которого мне не под силу без чьей-либо помощи.

Есть сайт.
На главной странице при прокрутке, либо если нажимать на рубрики в меню, либо вообще выполнять что-либо связанное с анимацией наблюдается глючность, рывки, не плавность. Причем в таком глючном стиле работает все. Иногда (совсем редко) внезапно все может работать быстро и плавно. Как определить из-за чего так происходит? Неужели со стилями css перебор или может с js? 
За любую помощь или наводки буду чрезмерно благодарен.

Comment: У меня глюков не наблюдается, всё очень плавно. Возможно стоит сменить браузер/железо/глаза? :)

Comment: Железо? core i7, 4GB RAM, 1GB видео. Я что-то сомневаюсь, что железо здесь не тянет. Глючит так во всех браузерах, я конечно же это проверил. Ну и глаза тоже протирал:)))

Comment: Ну из очевидного: Все сайты, которые я делаю с использованием тех же css, jquery  и т.д., у меня не глючат, вот именно этот сайт озадачил меня своими глюками.

Comment: f12 -> timeline

зачем пихать метки, которые гарантированно не относятся к вопросу?

Comment: @MatthewPatell, 4gb сейчас не очень много, у меня на ноуте часто все 6 со свопом забиваются.

Comment: @Etki, я это понимаю. Но не ужели с просто открытым  хромом с одной вкладкой в браузере он будет лагать? А что говорить про остальных людей, у которых далеко не 8, 6, 4 гб? Получается, у всех будет лагать. Проблема в сайте. Только вот где и какая...

Comment: @Etki, если бы я только знал, что к нему относится...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, почитайте - [Используем время простоя веб-приложения для фоновых задач (хабр)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/251939/).
Очень помогло мне с оптимизацией анимации. Не столько сама функция описанная там, сколько вообще знание специфики этой.

И там же в комментариях где-то [полезная ссылка на плагин (github)](https://github.com/lolmaus/jquery.timer-tools) для jquery.

Comment: @Zakhar  Morozov, спасибо. В дальнейшем мне это пригодится. Но сейчас вопрос поставлен так: Как понять из-за чего и почему глючит сайт. Ведь он глючит не только при прокрутке.

Comment: Можно ссылку на него хотя бы? А вообще да, через timeline палить только. Сравните таймлайн вашего сайт, например с этим.

Comment: @Zakhar  Morozov, сморю я в timline, и либо я торможу, либо что... Ссылка: top2.by

Comment: Да, сайт ужасно тормозит. По таймлайну много фпс тратится на отрисовку при скролле. Кто-то скажет, что глупость, но по моему личному опыту проблема в  - `background-size: cover`. И у вас два фона. Попробуйте замостить фон паттерном, что я и сделал через dev инструменты браузера, сайт стал просто летать. У вас там не композиция на фоне, так что не критично. Я не разработчик браузера, но судя по всему измененный размер фона отрисовывается каждую миллисекунду, при каком-либо действии, например скролле. Казалось бы, да? А такая заподлянка в ванильном css...

Comment: @Zakhar  Morozov, да, согласен, бэграунд здорово портит жизнь. Спасибо за наводку. Мне вот что еще интересно, даже без background-size: cover когда казалось бы уже все летает, у меня анимация центрального меню, и выпадающего меню на кнопке вход все равно работает не плавно.

Comment: @MatthewP, это уже вопрос к библиотекам, которые вы там используете. У меня без фона, на вашем сайте все плавно. Но я бы грешил на jquery UI. И еще плохая практика использовать `!important` в css, надо стараться избегать его. Помимо всего, еще и путаницу может вызвать в дальнейшем. Но он только на стадии генерации страницы нагрузки дает.

Comment: @MatthewP, и еще. Опять по таймлайну вижу, что фпс резко падает от 60+ до 30-, вр время появления модальных окон. И по таймлайну вижу же, что эти окна подгружаются по ajax. Вот вам и ответ.Увы, конкретных советов на этот счет дать не могу. Копайте и оптимизируйте в эту сторону. Пробуйте сначала генерировать полученный html, и спустя несколько милисекунд вызывать его. То есть разделять получение данных по ajax и анимацию.

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответы и дельные советы!!!

Answer (score 0):

А есть прикольная штука под названием [afterlag](http://serdmi.com/demo/afterlag/).

Comment: Прикольная, но не в моем случае. Лаги не проходят никогда.